# How to correctly use repaint() and revalidate()?

Tags: java, jpanel

I am new to JPanel and don't quite understand how to reset it. Once a picture is chosen and the user wants to select a new one, I want it to erase the old selected picture and paste the new one. But I'm not sure how. I've seen `repaint()` and `revalidate()` used, but I clearly don't know how to use it. So how do I accomplish this?

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JRadioButtonMenuItem;

public class Menu extends JFrame {
    JMenuBar menuBar;
    ButtonGroup pictureGroup, problemsGroup;
    BufferedImage picture1img, picture2img, picture3img;
    JMenu choiceOfThreePictures, numberOfProblems;
    JRadioButtonMenuItem picture1, picture2, picture3, fourProblems, nineProblems, sixteenProblems;
    // /Users/Administrator/Dropbox/Java/HW6Wilson/HW6Wilson/Picture1.jpg
    // /Users/Administrator/Dropbox/Java/HW6Wilson/HW6Wilson/Picture2.png
    // /Users/Administrator/Dropbox/Java/HW6Wilson/HW6Wilson/Picture3.jpg

    public Menu() {
        // Create the menu bar.
        menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        setJMenuBar(menuBar);

        // Create Picture choices on Menu Bar
        choiceOfThreePictures = new JMenu("Picture Choices");
        // Add Picture choices on Menu Bar
        menuBar.add(choiceOfThreePictures);
        // Create MenuItems onto Picture choices
        pictureGroup = new ButtonGroup();
        picture1 = new JRadioButtonMenuItem("Picture 1");
        picture2 = new JRadioButtonMenuItem("Picture 2");
        picture3 = new JRadioButtonMenuItem("Picture 3");
        // Add Picture Choices to Picutre choices menu
        choiceOfThreePictures.add(picture1);
        pictureGroup.add(picture1);
        choiceOfThreePictures.add(picture2);
        pictureGroup.add(picture2);
        choiceOfThreePictures.add(picture3);
        pictureGroup.add(picture3);

        // Create Number Of Problems on Menu Bar
        numberOfProblems = new JMenu("Number Of Problems");
        // Add Number Of problems on Menu Bar
        menuBar.add(numberOfProblems);
        // Create Menu Items onto Number Of problems
        problemsGroup = new ButtonGroup();
        fourProblems = new JRadioButtonMenuItem("4");
        nineProblems = new JRadioButtonMenuItem("9");
        sixteenProblems = new JRadioButtonMenuItem("16");
        // Add Number Of problems onto menu
        numberOfProblems.add(fourProblems);
        problemsGroup.add(fourProblems);
        numberOfProblems.add(nineProblems);
        problemsGroup.add(nineProblems);
        numberOfProblems.add(sixteenProblems);
        problemsGroup.add(sixteenProblems);

        // Start creating ActionListeners
        picture1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                System.out.println("Working");
                try {
                    picture1img = ImageIO.read(new File("/Users/Administrator/Dropbox/Java/HW6Wilson/HW6Wilson/Picture1.jpg"));
                    getContentPane().add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(picture1img)));
                    revalidate();
                    repaint();
                    setVisible(true);

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    System.out.println("Couldn't find image.");
                }
            }
        });
        picture2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                System.out.println("Working");
                try {
                    picture2img = ImageIO.read(new File("/Users/Administrator/Dropbox/Java/HW6Wilson/HW6Wilson/Picture2.jpg"));
                    getContentPane().add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(picture2img)));
                    revalidate();
                    repaint();
                    setVisible(true);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    System.out.println("Couldn't find image.");
                }
            }
        });
        picture3.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                System.out.println("Working");
                try {
                    picture3img = ImageIO.read(new File("/Users/Administrator/Dropbox/Java/HW6Wilson/HW6Wilson/Picture3.jpg"));
                    getContentPane().add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(picture3img)));
                    revalidate();
                    repaint();
                    setVisible(true);

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    System.out.println("Couldn't find image.");
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Menu mb = new Menu();
        mb.setSize(900, 700);
        mb.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        mb.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using it just fine, you can even remote `repaint()` call as revalidate is more then enought. The problem is, that you are **adding new images** but you are **not removing previously added images** from the `contentPane` that is why it is not switching.

So if you do

```
                    picture3img = ImageIO.read(new File("/Users/Administrator/Dropbox/Java/HW6Wilson/HW6Wilson/Picture3.jpg"));
                    getContentPane().removeAll(); // HERE IS IMPORTANT PART
                    getContentPane().add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(picture3img)));
                    revalidate();
```

It will work

The better approach would be to hold single label as a "image display" and use `setIcon(icon)` on `JLabel` insteed of changing whole labels.

Comment: Thank you so much! I spent so much time getting no where with that.